Ubuntu is muting my microphone on unmute (after "sound" settings page is started.) (BUG)
Ubuntu 24.10:
My "Zone Wireless" headset works fine. (as it did for years)
It has a mute button, and detects the mic-boom-position (and does  speech announcement of mute status)
Recently, that is until I go to "Sound" settings.
Once I open that part of settings - the mic gets disabled. of I move the mic or press the button, it gets enabled, then instantly disabled again.
Is there anything I can do to stop that pesky sabotage from sound settings (that starts once the panel is opened) ?

This question is similar to: How do I report a bug?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

good point, I am mostly out for a solution. - hoping there is some config that can me changed.
